# ZFS I/O Error, Kernel Panic during import

Tags: linux, raid, zfs, io, zfsonlinux

I'm running a raidz1-0 (RAID5) setup with 4 data 2TB SSDs.

During midnight, somehow 2 of my data disks experience some I/O error (from /var/log/messages).

When I investigated in the morning, the zpool status shows the following :

```
 state: SUSPENDED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to IO failures.
action: Make sure the affected devices are connected, then run 'zpool clear'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-HC
  scan: resilvered 1.36T in 0 days 04:23:23 with 0 errors on Thu Apr 20 21:40:48 2023
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zfs51       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          raidz1-0  UNAVAIL     36     0     0  insufficient replicas
            sdc     FAULTED     57     0     0  too many errors
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sde     UNAVAIL      0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: List of errors unavailable: pool I/O is currently suspended
```

I tried doing `zpool clear`, I keep getting the error message `cannot clear errors for zfs51: I/O error`

Subsequently, I tried rebooting first to see if it resolves - however there was issue shut-downing.

As a result, I had to do a hard reset. When the system boot back up, the pool was not imported.

Doing `zpool import zfs51` now returns me :

```
        Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source.
```

Even putting `-f` or `-F`, I get the same error. Strangely, when I do `zpool import -F`, it shows the pool and all the disks online :

```
   pool: zfs51
     id: 12204763083768531851
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

        zfs51       ONLINE
          raidz1-0  ONLINE
            sdc     ONLINE
            sdd     ONLINE
            sde     ONLINE
            sdf     ONLINE
```

Yet however, when importing by the pool name, the same error shows.

Even tried using `-fF`, doesn't work.

After scrawling through Google and reading up on different various ZFS issues, i stumbled upon the `-X` flag command (that solves users facing similar issue).

I went ahead to run `zpool import -fFX zfs51` and the command seems to be taking long.However, I noticed the 4 data disks having high read activity, which I assume its due to ZFS reading the entire data pool. But after 7 hours, all the read activity on the disks stopped.

I also noticed a ZFS kernel panic message :

```
 kernel:PANIC: zfs: allocating allocated segment(offset=6859281825792 size=49152) of (offset=6859281825792 size=49152)
```

Currently, the command `zpool import -fFX zfs51` seems to be still running (terminal did not return back the input to me). However, there doesnt seem to be any activity in the disks. Also running `zpool status` in another terminal seems to hanged as well.

1. I'm not sure what do at the moment - should I continue waiting (it has been almost 14 hours since I started the import command), or should I do another hard reset/reboot?
2. Also, I read that potentially I can actually import the pool as readonly (`zpool import -o readonly=on -f POOLNAME`) and salvage the data - anyone can any advise on that?
3. I'm guessing both of my data disks potentially got spoilt (somehow at the same timing) - how likely is this the case, or could it be due to ZFS issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ит ис цросспостед: https://serverfault.com/questions/1135313/zfs-i-o-error-kernel-panic-during-import